# Who invented the special left hand grouping for Chopin Ballade no. 4?

Tags: sheet-music, musicology

[image: Schiemer edition, edited by Rafael Joseffy]

Some editions of Chopin's 4<sup>th</sup> ballade has this 1/2/1/2 grouping, but apparently this is some kind of invention by later editors. Chopin's own writing, as well as most early editions, use the normal 3/3 grouping:

[image: Chopin's autograph]

My question is, who has taken such liberty to change <del>rhythm</del> altogether in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't change the rhythm. As far as I can see, both excerpts are rhythmically identical. The only difference is with the beaming, which *doesn't* affect the rhythm. However, I certainly prefer the way the Chopin manuscript is notated. Presumably, the printed version is notated in this way simply to keep the L.H. notes on the lower stave only.

Comment: I agree; I think the printed version also attempts to make the time signature for each hand clear (e.g. 3/4 Right Hand, 6/8 Left Hand) as well as reflect what's happening musically (notice the single 8th notes are marked staccato while the beamed notes are not.) That said, I do prefer Chopin's manuscript.

Comment: OK I should have been more careful about the choice of word since the changes indeed don't affect how it's played and how people perceive to listen in any obvious way, though the interpretation would have been a bit different.